# FOSUserBundle login without password

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have FOSUserBundle login system working correctly.

Now for my movile (iPad) system, I have a Thumbnails List with user picture + name and what I wanted to do is to be loged on the system by clicking his own picture, but it keeps asking for a password all the time and I didn´t see any configuration to allow users without password.

Any help or clue?

Comment: how do you now that the user is clicking his own picture if the user is not authenticated?

Comment: I have a Thumbnails ListView with their pictures. The user will select his own picture, but now I have all the users with the same passord and a form field hidden with password value typed manually.